# What does the property 'EffectiveAuditMask' in SPAudit class means?

Tags: spaudit

AuditFlags property(SPAudit Class) indicates the events which are to be audited. What is effective audit mask for ?? By default, I could see its value "None".

Answer (score 0):

[SPAudit.EffectiveAuditMask PropertyGets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spaudit.effectiveauditmask(v=office.15).aspx) or sets a value that indicates what kinds of events and actions are audited as specified for this object or from a higher scope, such as the site.

So this property usually return a numeric code which represnt the audit type.

check the example of it.http://sharepointstuff.net/2015/04/script-dump-audit-settings-for-all-site-collections-in-web-app/